# How to convert a group of xls 2 tab delimited files using ssis?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb6, ssis

How to convert a group of xls files into tab delimited files using ssis ?

Got a script for doing this on a google search.Please sugest me how to achieve this using ssis

```
    Dim objFSO, objFile, objFileTSV
    Dim strLine, strNewLine, strNewText
    Dim FileNameLength, LineLength, NewFileName, Linepos, Quote, QuoteCount, TotalFilesConverted

    objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    strCurPath = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    TotalFilesConverted = 0

    For Each objFile In objFSO.getfolder(strCurPath).Files
        If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".CSV" Then
            FileNameLength = Len(objFile.Name) - 4
            NewFileName = Left(objFile.Name, FileNameLength) & ".tsv"
            objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile, 1)

            Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
                strLine = objFile.ReadLine
                LineLength = Len(strLine)
                Linepos = 1
                strNewLine = ""
                Quote = False
                QuoteCount = 0

                Do While Linepos <= LineLength
                    If Mid(strLine, Linepos, 1) = "," And Not Quote Then
                        strNewLine = strNewLine + vbTab
                        Quote = False
                    ElseIf Mid(strLine, Linepos, 1) = Chr(34) Then
                        QuoteCount = QuoteCount + 1
                        If QuoteCount = 2 And Linepos <> LineLength Then
                            If Mid(strLine, Linepos, 2) = Chr(34) & Chr(34) Then
                                strNewLine = strNewLine + Chr(34)
                                Linepos = Linepos + 1
                                Quote = True
                                QuoteCount = 1
                            Else
                                Quote = False
                                QuoteCount = 0
                            End If
                        Else
                            Quote = True
                        End If
                    Else
                        strNewLine = strNewLine + Mid(strLine, Linepos, 1)
                    End If
                    Linepos = Linepos + 1
                Loop
                strNewText = strNewText & strNewLine & vbCrLf
            Loop
            objFile.Close()

            objFileTSV = objFSO.CreateTextFile(NewFileName)
            objFileTSV.WriteLine(strNewText)
            TotalFilesConverted = TotalFilesConverted + 1
            strNewText = ""
            objFileTSV.Close()

        End If
    Next

    MsgBox(CStr(TotalFilesConverted) + " Files Converted from CSV to TSV.")
```

It has been understood that ,this can be used in a script task..but let me have some clues

Comment: Why would you want to use vb6 in SSIS? It supports .Net

Comment: What is the relevance of that script to this problem? All it does is convert CSV files into TSV files.

Comment: That's a crazy way of doing things, you should be using the SSIS tasks to take a single xls file, pull the columns of interest and output them into a different file. Then if you have a batch of files to process in this way, the inner operation can be converted into a loop in various ways. Using a script is most likely going to be way slower too, although that may only be an issue when your file sizes start getting large.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no data transformation involved, the simplest way to do this would be to create a Data Flow Task with an Excel Source and a Flat File Destination. You should set Column Delimiter field to "Tab {t}" in the Flat File Connection Manager.

As you have multiple Excel files in your input, you can use a Foreach loop to do the above process for each file.